# Why my mybatis query result is null?

Tags: mybatis

I am completely new here.Could anyone please give me some help?My Syntax is as following.

PO:

```
package com.cabr.po;

public class InputVAT {

private String dept;
private String period;
private String tax;
private String type;
}
```

toString and get,set methods are ommited here.

Aliases in configuration:

```
<typeAliases>
    <package name="com.cabr.po" />
</typeAliases>
```

DaoImplement:

```
@Override
public InputVAT findInputVATByPeriod(String period) {
    SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();

    InputVAT inputVAT =        sqlSession.selectOne("com.cabr.findInputVATByPeriod", period);
    return inputVAT;
}
```

mapper:

```
<mapper namespace="com.cabr">
<select id="findInputVATByPeriod" parameterType="string"
    resultType="InputVAT">
    SELECT * FROM input_vat WHERE period = #{period}
</select>
```

test:

```
@Test
public void testFindInputVATByPeriod() {
    InputVATDao dao = new InputVATDaoImpl(sqlSessionFactory);
    InputVAT inputVAT = dao.findInputVATByPeriod("201607");
    System.out.println(inputVAT);
}
```

database:

```
CREATE TABLE `input_vat` (
`id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`dept` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`period` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
`tax` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I try to run this test,the console shows:

```
 2016-08-22 15:54:08,282 [main] [com.cabr.findInputVATByPeriod]-[DEBUG] ==>
 Preparing: SELECT * FROM input_vat WHERE period = ? 

2016-08-22 15:54:08,360 [main] [com.cabr.findInputVATByPeriod]-[DEBUG] ==> 
Parameters: 201607(String)

2016-08-22 15:54:08,462 [main] [com.cabr.findInputVATByPeriod]-[DEBUG] <==  
Total: 0

null
```

I wish I have descripted my problem clearly.I wonder why the result is null while there is actually data in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...I found some answers noticing that this may work:

```
<select id="findInputVATByPeriod" parameterType="string"
resultMap="MyresultMap">
SELECT * FROM input_vat WHERE period = #{period}
</select>

<ResultMap id="MyresultMap" type="InputVAT">
    <id column="id" property="id">
</ResultMap>
```

In fact I didn't save the data in my database correctly.What a shame!

Comment: And no need of mentioning the `<id column="xxx" xxxx>` attr also just ResultMap is enough